# Folder won't be created

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to make a program that uses a logging system, but the folder named 'Logs' won't get made in the host folder. Does anyone know why? This is the code I'm using (in command prompt):

```bat
:Boot
cd %userprofile%\Desktop\DeltaOS
if exist "Accounts" goto Home
if not exist "Accounts" md Accounts
goto Home
if exist "Logs" goto Home
if not exist "Logs" goto LogsSetup
:LogsSetup
md "Logs"
cd %userprofile%\Desktop\DeltaOS\Logs
md %date%
goto Home
:Home
cd %userprofile%\Desktop\DeltaOS\Logs\%date%
echo - DeltaOS was booted.> %time%
```

-- SOLVED --
The issue was that the system created the Accounts folder and thought the Logs folder also existed because of it. I've fixed it now.

Comment: When the folder Accounts exists the script jumps to the end and assumes the Logs folder exists

Answer (score 0):

This seems more simple than it is being made.

The `DATEDIR` variable should be created since the date may change between statements. If your DATE format is US English, it will have characters which cannot be used as a directory name.

```
:Boot
cd "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\DeltaOS"
if not exist "Accounts" (md Accounts)
SET "DATEDIR=%DATE:/=-%"
if not exist "Logs\%DATEDIR%" (md "Logs\%DATEDIR%")
cd "Logs\%DATEDIR%"
echo - DeltaOS was booted.>"%TIME::=-%"
```